# Updating create-react-app proxy settings from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've picked up a legacy project, and have been asked to update the `create-react-app` package from 1.0.3 to the latest.

The problem is, the new proxy settings aren't working; requests that were previously going to `my/resource.do` are just returning `index.html`

As suggested in the docs (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually), I took the 'proxy' object in `package.json` and converted it to instructions in a file called `setupProxy.js`. The new js file is definitely being read; I just can't get it to work.

Can anyone see where the mistake is here? This is exactly as specified in the docs, but for some reason requests that worked before are now failing.

Any help greatly appreciated

Before (in `package.json`)

```
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:9000"
    },
    "/some/thing": {
      "target": "https://example.org:8452/",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/some": {
      "target": "https://example.org:7324",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/.*": {
      "target": "https://example.org:8452/",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

After (in `setupProxy.js`):

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.use('/api', proxy({ target: 'http://localhost:9000/' }))

    app.use('/some/thing', proxy( 
        { 
            target: 'https://example.org:8452/',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            logLevel: 'debug'

        } 
    ))

    app.use('/some', proxy(
        { 
            target: 'https://example.org:7324/',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            logLevel: 'debug'
        } 
    ))

    app.use(proxy('/.*',
        {
            target: 'example.org:8452/',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            logLevel: 'debug'

        }
    ))

}
```